# Elasticsearch fails to run on the java version 1.8 on CentOS 7

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have downloaded the elesticsearch on the CentOS 7 server.
This server has the following version of java:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_141"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_141-b16)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.141-b16, mixed mode)
```

When I run the bin/elasticsearch it fails with the following error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.elasticsearch.tools.JavaVersionChecker
Elasticsearch requires at least Java 8 but your Java version from /bin/java does not meet this requirement
```

As you can see It says that it can't find the java 8.However the java -version indicates the current java version is 1.8.

I have tried a lot but can't solve this.
Please help me.

Comment: maybe the java location not match (/bin/java).
check by:
echo $(which java)
echo $JAVA_HOME

Comment: So how to set proper java location?Which env variable should be changed/checked?

Comment: try  `which java` , if the result is /bin/java

Comment: echo $(which java) returns /usr/bin/java./usr/bin/java -version
returns openjdk version "1.8.0_141"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_141-b16)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.141-b16, mixed mode)

Comment: make sure your JAVA_HOME and CLASSPATH set correct, share my setting (`/etc/profile.d/java.sh`):
`export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_131 && 
export CLASSPATH=.:$JAVA_HOME/lib/dt.jar:$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar`

Comment: Hi..I have tried with the different jdk with help of the JAVA_HOME env.But still no success.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150811/discussion-between-space-earth-and-chad-chen).